# Data Validation Error on third iteration.

Tags: google-apps-script

I have constructed the following function with in a larger program. The function creates a copy of a template file and adds some data to three cells of the new sheet. it does this for multiple copies of the same file with slightly different data.

Problem is that on the third time through the outer loop, I get this error. Its always for the second cell up date "origin".

"An attempt to set a spreadsheet value has failed due to the spreadsheet's data validation settings"

I have removed all protections, data validation, or conditional formating from the target sheet and stripped any formating. The frustrating thing is that it works just fine for the first two iterations.

```
  function AcceptanceTestingSheet(target_folder, container_num, item_code, origin)
  {
   //-------------Open and Copy the Acceptance Testing Template than fill with info-----
   var ATFile = DriveApp.getFileById('0AmkJld8rYr88dGFLWTEwNm5kMGtuNnRBTEppUlhIbnc');

 var current_AT_ss = ATFile.makeCopy(container_num + " AT " + item_code, target_folder);

   var AT_file_copy = SpreadsheetApp.open(current_AT_ss).getSheets()[0];

   AT_file_copy.getRange("data_item_code").setValue(item_code);

//this one is the problem.
   AT_file_copy.getRange("data_origin").setValue(origin);

   AT_file_copy.getRange("data_container_num").setValue(container_num);
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you defining the named ranges used in this function?

Comment: They are being defined in the calling functions, and the values added to the function call.

Comment: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var BOLValues = sheet.getRange("range_BOL_number").getValues(); var containerValues = sheet.getRange("range_container_num").getValues();
  var originValues = sheet.getRange("range_origin").getValues();
  var itemCodeValues = sheet.getRange("range_item_code").getValues();
  var QtyValues = sheet.getRange("range_qty").getValues();

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried defining the ranges like A1:B4 instead of passing a named range? And also, using Logger.log check if your range is actually being passed on. Just add, `Logger.log(data_origin)` just before the `AT_file_copy.getRange("data_origin").setValue(origin);` and see what value logs show. If it is undefined, it might be the case that the values are not being passed along.

Comment: That brings up an interesting point. I can not get logger.log(etc) to function in my scripts. The system does not seem to recognize it as a valid instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be that the base file I was copying was a old style spreadsheet. Copied it over to a new format sheet and it works fine.